# The Maximum Value of Signed Integer Types

Tags: c++, c, integer, signed

Is the maximum integer value of signed integer types guaranteed to be
`(uintmax_t)pow(2, sizeof(TYPE) * CHAR_BIT - 1) - 1`
in C and in C++?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your underlying question, but the maximum value for any numeric type `T` in C++ is `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`.

Comment: @cdhowie I am in a situation that I exactly need to know how a signed integer is represented with compatibility in both languages. Simply knowing the maximum value doesn't help now.

Comment: To what end? Perhaps if you asked *that* question instead, we could be a bit more helpful. (This question smells of [the XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).)

Comment: @xiver77 Perhaps you need to ask a second question to home in on exactly what you need to know.

Comment: Well, since the statement in my question appears false, I need to find another route somehow. That's all actually.

Comment: @xiver77: I've updated my answer. C explicitly permits padding bits for integer types; I'm less sure about C++.

Comment: Do you really have to care about padding bits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Integer types are permitted to have *padding bits* which do not contribute to the value. For example, a 32-bit signed integer type with 8 padding bits would have a maximum value of 2<sup>23</sup>-1, or `16777215`, rather than 2<sup>31</sup>-1, or `2147483647`.

This is stated explicitly in the C standard.  I haven't found similar wording in the C++ standard, but I *think* C++ also permits integer types to have padding bits.

But very few compilers take advantage of this permission.

To determine the maximum value of an integer type, use the appropriate `*_MAX` macro defined in `<limits.h>`, or in C++ use `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` as suggested by cdhowie's comment.

(Incidentally, the `pow` function is not the best way to denote the value you're asking about. It's a floating-point function, and its result may be inexact in some cases.)

Comment: I have just one more question! Is my statement true if that is the **maximum of the maximum** value of a signed integer type?

Comment: @xiver77: I don't know what you mean. If you're asking about the widest supported integer type, it's permitted to have padding bits, at least in C.

Comment: What I mean is that can a weird implementation for example have a 16bit signed integers maximum as 2^15+2000 while its minimum is -4, just for example.

Comment: So.. can |INT_MAX| > |INT_MIN|?

Comment: @xiver77: At least in C, signed integer types are symmetric, except for an optional extra negative value. Padding bits are unspecified. Values of padding bits do not affect the value, but might create a trap representation. (In practice, you're *very* unlikely to find anything other than 2's-complement with no padding bits.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Why? I recall trap representations being allowed even without padding bits. I.e. having INT_MIN==-INT_MAX and one trap representation with all bits one is legal IIRC.

Comment: @MSalters: Right, it's implementation-defined whether what would normally be the most negative value (for 2's-complement) or `-0` (for 1's-complement and sign-and-magnitude) is a trap representation or not. In the absence of padding bits, those are the only possible trap representations. And the vast majority of modern systems use 2's-complement with no trap representations and no padding bits (and thus an asymmetric range for signed integers). Anything else would be quite exotic, even if it's permitted by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "maximum integer value".

If you are asking whether it's guaranteed that a specific implementation will support that maximum value, the answer is no.

But if you are asking whether it's guaranteed that no implementation can exceed that maximum value, the answer is yes.

A positive value in a signed integer can have at most *n-1* value bits, where *n* is the number of bits in the data type. So *2 <sup>n-1</sup>-1* is the maximum possible value of a signed integer of *n* bits.

No implementation can have a higher maximum, but they can have a lower maximum.